# Java Generic Type syntax

Tags: java, generics, syntax

```
<D extends com.j256.ormlite.dao.Dao<T,?>,T> D getDao(Class<T> clazz)
```

I am not able to understand above statement

getDao(Class clazz) returns D

D having following constraints

```
D extends com.j256.ormlite.dao.Dao<T,?>
```

and extra **,T** i am not able to understand.

Could you please explain it ?

Comment: This method requires two type parameters, `D` and `T`, and `D` has an additional `extends` constraint, depending on `T`. Don't get confused by this `<T,?>,T`, those do not belong together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method has *two* type parameters, `D` and `T`, with `D` having an additional `extends` constraint, depending on `T`. Don't get confused by this `<T,?>,T` syntax; the `,T` does *not* belong to the constraint, but is the second parameter, telling Java that `T` is not the name of a concrete class.

If you add a space or swap the parameters, it will be clearer. Here's a similar, but somewhat simpler example. These method signatures are all equivalent:

```
<D extends List<T>,T>   D createListOf(Class<T> clazz)  // your version
<D extends List<T>, T>  D createListOf(Class<T> clazz)  // extra space
<T, D extends List<T>>  D createListOf(Class<T> clazz)  // different order
```

Keep in mind that, even though it may seem apparent that `T` is another type parameter, this is not clear to Java. There could be an actual class named `T`, so we have to be explicit that `T` is a type parameter.

```
class T { ... } // this T is not what I want!
```

Conversely, type parameters are not restricted to single characters. You could also have a type parameter called `Foo`, or even `String`, if you want to utterly confuse your co-workers. Maybe that makes clear why the declaration of all type parameters using `<...>` is necessary.

```
// just a deterrent example; don't do this! String as parameter, not class
<String, Foo extends List<String>> Foo createListOf(Class<String> clazz)
```

Comment: \@tobias_kas you are saying seconds parameter of return type is too just tell Java that T is not the name of a concrete class. is it same information can also convey with first parameter itself ?

Comment: @AmitYadav You mean, shouldn't it be enough that `T` is used in the constraint for `D`? No. There's no rule that a class name must have more than one letter, thus `T` could as well the the name of a concrete class.

Comment: \@tobias_k I agree with you that we can create a class of name T. I think I don't have enough knowledge on Generic type. All you mean to say that in return type T as 2nd parameter is to inform java that T is not a concrete class...hope later i'll under stand this concept. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This method will:

- Return an object of type `D`
- Where `D` is or extends `com.j256.ormlite.dao.Dao`, parametrized with an object of type `T` or extending/implementing `T` and an unknown type parameter
- If given as argument a class of type `T`

It uses a lot of generic abstraction, which is not surprising given it delivers a DAO (Data Access Object).

Comment: I am confusing about return type. It returns D <1st constraints, 2nd constraints> 1st constraints = D extends com.j256.ormlite.dao.Dao<T,?> it fine for me...I am asking is it 2nd constraints really needed ?

Comment: I think I see what you mean. Since it's a generic method, the type parameter `T` must be declared there. Otherwise it could not be referenced by the method parameter, nor by the parametrization of `com.j256.ormlite.dao.Dao`.

Comment: \@Mena I am not confused with method arguments T instead return type T mentioned as a second parameter <1st parameter, T> D